# How to enable cache busting (versioning) for javascript "imports" in Spring Boot?

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp, caching

Spring `ResourceUrlEncodingFilter` does not version URIs in JavaScript `import` statmenets. The file **main.js** itself is versioned but the import inside it pointing to **map.js** is not. This is true for both `Content` and `Version` strategies.

**script element in JSP:**

```
<script type="module" src="<c:url value="/main.js"/>"></script>
```

**main.js**:

```
import {createMap} from "/map.js";

// code...
```

**application.properties**:

```
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.max-age=365d
spring.resources.chain.enabled=true
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.enabled=true
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.paths=/**
```

**ResourceUrlEncoderFilter** (because not auto-configured for JSP):

```
@Component
public class CacheBusterMVCConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnEnabledResourceChain
    public ResourceUrlEncodingFilter resourceUrlEncodingFilter() {
        return new ResourceUrlEncodingFilter();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that this DOES work for CSS imports, so it should be possible for module imports as well.

In the meantime, I wrote a shell script that adds the file's md5 hash as a request parameter to files in import statements.

https://gist.github.com/erbrecht/e2c34456f44de6652baed858ebad4ede

This script sits in the root of my project.

I'm using the `exec-maven-plugin` to run this script after the `validate` phase:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <executions>
        <execution><!-- Update es6 import statements to include content hash -->
            <id>Updating ES6 imports to use file content hash</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>bash</executable>
                <commandlineArgs>jsResourceTransformer.sh</commandlineArgs>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I know this is not at all a portable solution for several reasons. I'll use it to get by until a more official/portable solution becomes available. Maybe it will help someone else as well.